# scanf when reading string not giving expected result

Tags: c, string, stdio

I a new programmer at C and I'm struggling with problems involving string, I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXNOME 60


typedef struct aluno
{

    char codigo[5];
    char nome[MAXNOME];
    char cpf[11];
    char periodo[6];

} aluno;

void adicionaAluno(){

    aluno novoAluno;

    // adiciona codigo do aluno 
    printf("\nDigite o codigo do aluno: "); 
    scanf("%s", novoAluno.codigo);
       
    // adiciona cpf do aluno
    printf("\nDigite o CPF do aluno: ");
    scanf(" %s", novoAluno.cpf);

    printf("\nDigite o periodo do aluno: ");
    scanf(" %s", novoAluno.periodo);

    // adiciona nome do aluno
    printf("\nDigite o nome do aluno: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", novoAluno.nome);
    printf("%s\n", novoAluno.nome);
    printf("%s\n", novoAluno.cpf);
    printf("%s\n", novoAluno.codigo);
    printf("%s\n", novoAluno.periodo);
}

int main(){
    adicionaAluno();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it with the following input:

```
Digite o codigo do aluno: 19404

Digite o CPF do aluno: 11122233344

Digite o periodo do aluno: 2020.1

Digite o nome do aluno: Bruno Mello
```

I would expect it would return:

```
Bruno Mello
11122233344
19404
2020.1
```

But instead, it returns:

```
Bruno Mello
111222333442020.1
19404Bruno Mello
2020.1
```

I simply can't understand why this is happening, can someone explain why this code isn't working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

char cpf[11]; should hold space also for a terminating character '\0'.
So in your case it should be at least 12.

In memory, after cpf comes periodo, which when scanned overidses cpf[11], which coincides with periodo[0] which results in seeing 111222333442020.1 printed.
Note the same applies for periodo, only you don't have another variable that you override after it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm used to coding in python and don't know these little nuances, how can I fix the code?

Comment: It should have the length equal to the 'largest string you want to hold in it + 1'. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm for more info